# Why do I get extra rows in LEFT JOIN when joining to an ID and TIMESTAMP column?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a table that contains multiple registration periods (date and time for the start of the registration, as well as date and time for when that instance of registration ends). For each row (registration period), there is a status column that contains the status at the end of the registration period. I was trying to get the status associated with the most recent end date of registration per a given ID. I've used a window function to get the most recent end date of interest per ID, and then I wanted to LEFT JOIN on ID and end date to get the status from the same table on which I used the window function. There should really just be one just one combination for a given end date and status per ID, but somehow I get more rows that what's in the left table.

Like I mentioned earlier, my approach was to use a window function to get `MAX(end_date)` per ID and some other column, let's call it `enrollment_number`. Then use LEFT JOIN on this table and its parent table to bring in status associated with that date only. Later, I'd like to use the result of this join to bring in the status associated with the end date into other tables where I need it.

```
WITH
     my_first_test AS
     (
    SELECT my_id,
           enrollment_number,
           MAX(end_date_of_enrollment) OVER (partition by my_id, enrollment_number) AS end_date_enrolled
    FROM enrollments
     )

SELECT mft.my_id, mft.end_date_enrolled, e.status
FROM my_first_test AS mft
LEFT JOIN enrollments AS e
                  ON mft.my_id = e.my_id AND mft.end_date_enrolled = e.end_date_enrolled;
```

The CTE returns 42917 rows, same number of rows as in the `enrollments` table, which it should be if I understand it correctly.

Then, I LEFT JOIN `enrollments`, to bring in information from the `status` column also contained in the `enrollments` table. The LEFT JOIN is done on `my_id` and `end_date_enrolled`.

I expect 42917 rows in the resulting table, because `my_id` and `end_date_enrolled` together should be unique. However, I get slightly more rows in my final table - 44408. I was wondering if the StackOverflow community would be able to help me solve this mystery. I am using SQL in AWS Redshift.

Comment: You must have duplicate entries.... you should make sure that the primary key is set correctly so that no two records ever have the same id

Answer (score 1):

You have duplicates in `enrollments`.  You can find them with aggregation:

```
SELECT my_id, end_date_enrolled, COUNT(*)
FROM enrollments AS e
GROUP BY my_id, end_date_enrolled
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Comment: Thank you, that was silly of me not to have checked that - I definitely did not expect any duplicated in `enrollments`.